# returning the output of a callback function from a javascript function

Tags: jquery, callback

I am showing a Delete confirmation dialogue box, and I want the result of User's click of YES or NO as TRUE or FALSE

Now, since Javascript function is **asynchronous**, the variable **yesDelete** in the code below does not wait for the users choice of confirmation.

Now, is there a way to return the value **r** as the returnvalue of the function ShowDeleteConfirm()?

```
function ShowDeleteConfirm() { 
    var yesDelete=false;

    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {

        yesDelete = r;

    }); 

    return yesDelete;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to pass a callback function as an argument either to `ShowDeleteConfirm()` or to `jConfirm()`.  Something like this:

```
function ShowDeleteConfirm(callback) {

    //someone correct me if I'm out of scope here...
    jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {

        callback(r);

    });
}
```

I think that will work, but I'm not sure if `callback` is in the scope of jConfirm's callback.  Worth a shot though :)

The otherway to do it would be to have the jConfirm callback function set a property on the `window` object where it's globally visible.

Anyway, hope that helps a little at least...

**EDIT**

Because JS is asynchronous, I'm don't think you can have `ShowDeleteConfirm()` return `true` or `false` based on the users input.  Hence the need to pass in a different callback function: `ShowDeleteConfirm(yourCallbackFunctionHere)`.   You could do this:

```
ShowDeleteConfirm(function(result) {
    //result should be true or false
});
```

but I think that's as close as you're going to get.  If that doesn't work for you, then you should probably think about changing your design to accommodate the fact that JS is asynchronous.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 - This should work. Here is a fiddle that shows this technique using a jQuery UI dialog. http://jsfiddle.net/jeWkB/3/

Comment: Thank you Ian for your reply. It is almost there. But when I fiddled, both OK and Cancel buttons returned TRUE. When I call, say "var result=ShowDeleteConfirm()", the variable "result" should be  either true or false. That is all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Anyway, what you gave me was of use. But still, I will try another login.

Answer (score 0):

I think following will be ur case:

```
 if (ShowDeleteConfirm()){
 myFunc();
    }

function ShowDeleteConfirm() { 

var yesDelete=false;

jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {

    yesDelete = r;
 }); 

return yesDelete;

}
```

should be like this:

ShowDeleteConfirm(myFunc);

```
        function ShowDeleteConfirm(myFunc) {     

        jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function (r) {    
if (r){            
myFunc();
}
         }); 


        }
```

Comment: Hi Brij,I think you are very close to my solution. Suppose I say var yes = ShowDeleteConfirm(); the value of YES should be TRUE or FALSE depending on users click. When I tried, the return value was undefined. When I give an alert, the returnvalue is given even before the dialogue box is displayed. (An asynchronous operation) Thanks.